# can someone help me translate this script to cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

```
#! /bin/sh

JBOSS_SERVER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/otcm-server
JBOSS_DEPLOY=$JBOSS_SERVER/deploy
JBOSS_LIB=$JBOSS_SERVER/lib
JBOSS_CONF=$JBOSS_SERVER/conf
JBOSS_WEB=$JBOSS_DEPLOY/ROOT.war

mkdir $1
cp $1.tar $1
cd $1
tar -xvf $1.tar
rm $1.tar
cd ..

cp $1/*.xml $JBOSS_DEPLOY
cp $1/*.ear $JBOSS_DEPLOY
cp $1/*.sar $JBOSS_DEPLOY
cp $1/*.jar $JBOSS_LIB

cp $1/lib/* $JBOSS_LIB

cp $1/conf/* $JBOSS_CONF

rm -rf $JBOSS_SERVER/tmp
rm -rf $JBOSS_SERVER/work
```

as you can see from the script i need to move the tar to another folder then unzip the content, after that i copy the contents from that tar to their respective folders.

the main part i cant get working is the unzipping part...

Comment: Why not just use cygwin ? Then you wouldn't need to translate scripts such as this. Go to: http://cygwin.com

Comment: @PaulR i am actually using cygwin to run this script. but all my work is done in windows and i only need that script to move files around so i was hoping to get some sort of unzipping program to work with cmd then moving the files using cmd as well. if i use cygwin i would need to do manual work but with cmd i can write up a list of commands and let the computer do its thing..

Comment: Why do you think you need to do "manual work" if you use cygwin rather than cmd ? You can just run the above script "as is". Am I missing something ?

Comment: what i meant was i have to open cygwin and cmd.. i was gonna just write up a perl script since i can run it through cmd =/

Comment: But you can just do everything in a cygwin shell - you don't need a cmd window open too. All the usual DOS executables can be invoked directly from cygwin.

Comment: i know im been silly lols. i use eclipse for all my work and everything is on desktop so i try to keep everything "window" rather than using something else.. as of now im using cygwin until i can find the proper cmd "script".. thanks!

Comment: Think of cygwin as a *superset* of cmd - you can do all the usual cmd stuff AND all the *nix stuff all from the same window. No need to limit yourself to cmd and DOS commands.

Comment: ya ill do that then! move stuff around.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the ss64 website bash section](http://ss64.com/bash/). Find your commands, and look up the equivalent windows command. Note that windows does not have tar and you will need to install it, or an alternative.

Comment: @JoeChen Not all of the commands are preinstalled by default on windows. [check here](http://ss64.com/links/windows.html) for links to the resource kits that include the rest of the commands. Also note, some BASH commands do not have windows equivalents, such as ftp, sftp, and ssh. You will not to find 3rd party command line replacements, use cygwin, or build something in a programming language such as python or perl.